# How to find out customers that only shopped in one store using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata

I want to see the number of customers who only shopped in one specific store during a specific period, so I wrote the following SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT CARD_NUMBER)
FROM <TRANSACTION TABLE>
WHERE DATE BETWEEN ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE) AND ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE)
AND STORE_NUMBER = 1234;
```

What if these customers (card holders) shop in other store chains?

I couldn’t use 
`AND CARD_NUMBER NOT IN…`
Because we have too many stores.
Any syntax that could be used here to solve this problem?

Comment: Consider using a `NOT EXISTS` predicate. In fact, many database optimizers will rewrite a `NOT IN (...)` to a `NOT EXISTS`. Alternatively, you could do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` back to the transaction table where the store number <> 1234 and add `WHERE checkTable.column is null` to the where clause.

Comment: `mysql` or `teradata`?

Answer (score 2):

If all transactions are within a single store, then MIN & MAX are the same:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
 ( 
   SELECT CARD_NUMBER
   FROM <TRANSACTION TABLE>
   WHERE DATE BETWEEN ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE) AND ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE)
   GROUP BY CARD_NUMBER
   HAVING MIN(STORE_NUMBER) = 1234  -- shopped in this store
       AND MAX(STORE_NUMBER) = 1234  -- but no other store 
 ) dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to know how many customers shopped ONLY at store 1234 during a given time period.

I think this does it:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT CARD_NUMBER)
  FROM <TABLE>
 WHERE DATE BETWEEN ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE) AND ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE)
   AND STORE_NUMBER = 1234
   AND CARD_NUMBER NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT CARD_NUMBER
                             FROM <TABLE>
                            WHERE DATE BETWEEN ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE)
                                           AND ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE)
                              AND STORE_NUMBER <> 1234);
```

The sub-select is giving you a list of card numbers where that shopped somewhere else during that time period. So, you're saying, "Show me all the card numbers from a given date for store 1234 where that number doesn't appear in the list of card numbers used at a different store."

Hope that helps

Comment: The issue here is that he said: `I couldn’t use AND CARD_NUMBER NOT IN… Because we have too many stores`

Comment: I took that to mean that he couldn't enumerate them all and that perhaps he didn't know about sub-selects. The answer provided by @dnoeth below is better anyway. :-)  Didn't see it until after I posted mine.

Comment: Depends on the size of the database and the amount of sort space available. The group by might blow the sort space on some smaller boxes if the dataset is too large.

Comment: if CARD_NUMBER is nullable then it's possible no rows will be returned. You should add `and CARD_NUMBER IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

add another select statement in your NOT IN clause ... AND NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT STORE_NUMBER FROM FOO WHERE STORE_NUMBER != 1234)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, many database optimizers will rewrite a `NOT IN (...)` to a `NOT EXISTS`. In your case either a `NOT EXISTS` and a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` would work...

Using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT CARD_NUMBER)
FROM <TRANSACTION TABLE> T
WHERE DATE BETWEEN ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE) AND ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE)
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM <TRANSACTION TABLE> T
  WHERE DATE BETWEEN ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE) AND ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE)
  AND STORE_NUMBER <> 1234
)
AND STORE_NUMBER = 1234;
```

Using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT CARD_NUMBER)
FROM <TRANSACTION TABLE> T
LEFT OUTER JOIN  <TRANSACTION TABLE> CHECK
    ON  T.CARD_NUMBER = CHECK.CARD_NUMBER
    AND CHECK.DATE BETWEEN ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE) AND ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE)
    AND STORE_NUMBER <> 1234
WHERE T.DATE BETWEEN ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE) AND ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE)
AND T.STORE_NUMBER = 1234
AND CHECK.CARD_NUMBER IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With card_list as (
-- get the custs that shopped 1234
select CARD_NUMBER
FROM <TRANSACTION TABLE>
WHERE DATE BETWEEN ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE) AND ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE)
AND STORE_NUMBER = 1234

EXCEPT
-- Remove from the above list those that shopped other stores

-- get the custs that shopped all other stores
select CARD_NUMBER
FROM <TRANSACTION TABLE>
WHERE DATE BETWEEN ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE) AND ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE)
AND STORE_NUMBER <> 1234
)

-- get the counts, this is already a unique list so no distinct needed.
select count(CARD_NUMBER) from card_list;'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
 ( 
   SELECT CARD_NUMBER
    FROM <TRANSACTION TABLE>
    WHERE DATE BETWEEN ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE) AND ‘XXXX-XX-XX’(DATE)
    AND STORE_NUMBER = '1234'
    GROUP BY CARD_NUMBER
    HAVING COUNT(CARD_NUMBER) = 1
  ) dt;
```

Comment: This checks for customers who shopped exactly once in this specific shop, but doesn't deal with other shops or multiple purchases.

Comment: @dnoeth perhaps `COUNT(DISTINCT STORE_NUMBER) =1` then

Comment: @ConradFrix: No, this will return always `1`, because there's a WHERE-condition on  `STORE_NUMBER = '1234'`

Comment: @dnoeth doh :) I guess you could move the `STORE_NUMBER = '1234' outside the inline view. e..g first find all cards used only in one store. Now limit it to just store 1234

Comment: @ConradFrix: Of course there are ways to fix it, that's why I wrote my 1st comment (btww, I didn't downvote). Finally it will be quite be similar to my answer :)

Comment: @dnoeth nah MAX = MIN is much slicker which is why I upvoted it.